# Комментарий не соответствует своей разметке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, комментарии, markdown

Смотрю на [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757949/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/757953?noredirect=1#comment1172758_757953) и вижу такой текст:
I'm looking at the [comment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757949/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/757953?noredirect=1#comment1172758_757953) and see following text:

> onSubmit = event => { event.preventDefault(); axios.post('[localhost:3000/newEmployee'](http://localhost:3000/newEmployee');, this.inp.value) } render() { return <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>  this.inp = inp} /> <input type="submit" value="Добавить" /> </form> } – Nikita21 21 минуту назад

[image: скриншот комментария]

Обращаю внимание на точку с запятой после ссылки.
Take a look at the semicolon after the link.

Но если посмотреть разметку этого комментария, то она такая:
But if I look at the comment markup, I'll see:

```
onSubmit = event => {
      event.preventDefault(); 
      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/newEmployee', this.inp.value)
  }    render() { return
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input type="text" ref={inp => this.inp = inp} />
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
        </form> }
```

[image: скриншот разметки]

Как видно, никакой точки с запятой там нет. Так что же она делает в отображении?
There's no any semicolon there. Why is it shown in formatted comment?

Comment: «обращаю внимание» // для таких случаев придумали красные рукописные круги (FHRC), чтобы глаза не ломать.

Comment: onSubmit = event => {
      event.preventDefault(); 
      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/newEmploye', this.inp.value)
  }    render() { return
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input type="text" ref={inp => this.inp = inp} />
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
        </form> }

Comment: воспроизводится :-)

Comment: какая-то проблема в кавычке

Comment: А если без запятой? 'https://localhost:3000/newEmploye'

Comment: ^^ Походу точка с запятой появляется после любой ссылки в кавычках.

Comment: onSubmit = event => {
      event.preventDefault(); 
      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/newEmployee', this.inp.value)
  }    render() { return
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input type="text" ref={inp => this.inp = inp} />
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
        </form> }